# nested div results in inline-elements in bootstrap3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using `Bootstrap 3.1.1`. I find that enclosing `<div class="input-group col-lg-3">` results in stacking of input boxes as shown below, while doing a nested

```
<div class-"col-lg-3">
    <div class="input-group>
        ....
    </div>
</div>
```

results in `inline-elements`. I would like to know if there is any logical reasoning behind this?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter price">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter price">
            <span class="input-group-addon">per item</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter price">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="input-group col-lg-3">
        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter price">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group col-lg-3">
        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter price">
        <span class="input-group-addon">per item</span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group col-lg-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter price">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I don't realy understand the question.

Comment: @Filly: did you use boostrap3.1.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the default css for an input-group[class*=col-] removes the float and padding.

Here's the rule:

```
.input-group[class*=col-] {
  float: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

This overrides the normal column css which is dependent on float left so the columns sit side-by-side and 15px of padding to create the column gutters.

Not to have this effect, you can override or remove this rule, wrap your input-group in a separate element (as you have done) or use one of the combination of forms/form-groups/input-groups in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

From the Bootstrap documentation:

> ## [Input groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups)
>
> ### Don't mix with other components
>
> Do not mix form groups or grid column classes directly with input groups. Instead, nest the input group inside of the form group or grid-related element.

In other words, `<div class="input-group col-lg-3">` is wrong. Instead you should write:

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="input-group">
```